# vagrant - no space left on device error

Tags: vagrant

I am new to vagrant. I am following the instructions at http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

I am getting the following error on running "sudo ./postinstall.sh" script

```
+ apt-get -y clean
+ rm -f /var/lib/dhcp3/*
+ rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
rm: cannot remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules': Is a directory
+ mkdir /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules': File exists
+ rm -rf /dev/.udev/
+ rm /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
rm: cannot remove `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules': No such file or directory
+ rm -f /home/vagrant/{*.iso,postinstall*.sh}
+ dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M
dd: writing `/EMPTY': No space left on device
78504+0 records in
78503+0 records out
82316406784 bytes (82 GB) copied, 105.122 s, 783 MB/s
+ rm -f /EMPTY
+ exit
```

But I seem to have enough space:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/precise64-root                  79G  2.3G   73G   3% /
udev                                       174M     0  174M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                       74M  272K   73M   1% /run
none                                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                       183M     0  183M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                                  228M   25M  192M  12% /boot
/vagrant                                   220G   91G  130G  42% /vagrant
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks  220G   91G  130G  42% /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/cookbooks  220G   91G  130G  42% /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/cookbooks
```

Can somebody please help? Thank you.

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 9):

It's supposed to do this :) It's making your virtual disk as small as possible since it is thinly provisioned.

Creating a file full of zeros on the disk until it is full is clearing the blocks on the disk and as such your file representing the VMs disk will be as small as the actual data you have on the disk.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, the explanation below is technically correct but misleading, since this isn't an error in the script, but the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

The problem resides in the following statement:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M
```

If you don't specify `count=<some value>`, the `dd` command will continue until the end of device is reached. So basically with the above command you're trying to create a file called that spawns through the whole partition, called `EMPTY` under `/`. Thus the error.

Comment: Thank you Emyl. So the script writes an empty file on all the free space and then removes the file. I am not sure what count does. I read on a blog "Other options include 'bs' to define the size of blocks of data to operate on and 'count' to tell the command how many blocks of data to process. If these options are omitted then the default block size of 512 bytes is used and data is processed either continuously or until either the end of the input data is reached or an error occurs." I want to process data continuously until the end is reached. There is already an if condition in the script.

Comment: What you're trying to do? As an example, adding count=1024 will create a 1Gb file (1M * 1024)